# google tag not registering any adword conversions - no errors presented

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ads, google-ads-api

I am using Adwords conversion to install an onClick conversion on my `reactjs` platform. Here is the index file.

```
    <!-- Google analytics verification -->
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="CONTENT"/>
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Ads: 1007901507 -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=ID"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'ID');
</script>



<!-- Event snippet for Submit Event Quote conversion page
In your html page, add the snippet and call gtag_report_conversion when someone clicks on the chosen link or button. -->
<script>
  function gtag_report_conversion(url, value) {
    var callback = function () {
      if (typeof(url) != 'undefined') {
        window.location = url;
      }
    };

    gtag('event', 'conversion', {
      'send_to': 'ID/TRACKING_ID',
      'transaction_id': '',
      'value': value,
      'currency': 'GBP',
      'event_callback': callback
    });
    return false;
  }
</script>
```

and the execution of the tag is in a simple onClick function:

```
  signUpAndSubmitEvent(event) {
    const BOOKING_VALUE = parseInt(event.budget) * 0.05;
    window.gtag_report_conversion(window.url, BOOKING_VALUE);
}
```

The tag is not registering any conversions and there are no errors presented. The conversion function is successfully called and executed and that has been tested in the console.

Any ideas?